# URL for ajax not working properly in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I recently added some url re-writing to my web application and had to added Page.Resolve URL to all my script images etc references. Now inside of those scripts, i have some ajax calls that now is not finding my webservices anymore. the Request URL is wrong i see looking at the error message. Is there anyway I can get to my webservices? thanks for any help.

What I had orginally thats not working now

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../MainService.asmx/UpdateInformation",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: parameter,
                dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and replace the `url` parameter with:

```
url: "/MainService.asmx/UpdateInformation",
```

or

```
url: "MainService.asmx/UpdateInformation",
```

Comment: Yes. One is relative to the root, the other to the current file location.

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
url: '<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/MainService.asmx/UpdateInformation")%>',
```

This will resolve the correct URL independently of the path the user is on. Note the `~`. This means that the path will start at the root of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Could always add something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% var siteroot = Url.Content("~/") %>

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: siteroot  + "MainService.asmx/UpdateInformation",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: parameter,
            dataType: "json",

</script>
```